# How to remove a special character in my curl output using grep,sed or awk

Tags: grep, curl, newlines, json

I'm trying to remove `\r\n` in the output of my curl 
my code is:

```
curl -s -u ian.guinto:W0lfg@ng131994 --request GET --url 'https://jira.toro.io/rest/api/2/issue/OJTSYSAD-829/comment' -H "Content-Type: application/json" | jsonpp | grep body | cut -d ':' -f2
```

that will output.

```
 "Test comment",
 "test comment 2\r\n",
 "test comment3\r\nTest comment 4\r\n",
```

my expect out put is:

```
 "Test comment",
 "test comment 2",
 "test comment3 Test comment 4",
```

Comment: it would help if you post output of `grep body`... you can use sed/awk to remove `\r\n`

Comment: I've tried `sed 's/\r\n//g' `

Comment: try `sed 's/\\r\\n//g'`

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with just JQ:

```sh
$ curl -L -O -u ian.guinto:W0lfg@ng131994 \
jira.toro.io/rest/api/2/issue/OJTSYSAD-829/comment

$ jq '.comments[].body | rtrimstr("\r\n") | gsub("\r\n"; " ")' comment
"Test comment"
"test comment 2"
"test comment3 Test comment 4"
```

http://github.com/stedolan/jq